# how to install driver wireless at ubuntu

Tags: wireless, drivers

How do I install my wireless driver at Ubuntu 12.10? This is my driver:

$ lspci | grep Wireless

06:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please run the command:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your device  Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01) ? If so, then the driver ath9k is already installed. Check to see if it is loaded:

```
lsmod
```

Is the wireless switch set to enable or disable wireless?

```
rfkill list all
```

Look for clues in the message logs:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath
```